# Is this some sort of directional derivative problem I have here?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $V = y^2U_{1} - xU_{3}$. Also, let $f = xy$ and $g = z^3$

Compute $V[f]$ and $V[g]$.

Now $U_{1} = (1,0,0)$ and $U_{3} = (0,0,1)$

Now in my notes, $V_{p}[f] = \displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}(f(p + tv))$ for $t = 0$. Is $V[f]$ just $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}(f(tv))$ then?

I apologize if this is confusing. I am confused too as to what the question is asking me to do here.

Answer (score 1):

$V[f] = (y^2U_1-xU_3)[xy] = y^2\partial_x(xy)-x\partial_z(xy)= y^3$.

$V[g] = (y^2U_1-xU_3)[z^3] = y^2\partial_x(z^3)-x\partial_z(z^3)= -3xz^2$.

See page 15 in the second edition of Barret O'neil's Elementary Differential Geometry, revised second edition. Once we get past the definition, it is as if $U_j = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$. Although, technically, this is just $U_j$ acting on $f$, I think $U_j$ is just a passive object if I read the text correctly. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Quick question. How do you know to take the partial derivative of $x$ followed by the partial derivative of $z$? What indicates that? Do we ever take the partial derivative of $y$?

Comment: Oh wait a minute. I see. There is no $U_{2}$. That is why we would not differentiate ever in terms of $y$

Comment: Correct. Also, I am calculating these directional derivatives at the point $(x,y,z)$. If we had $p=(a,b,c)$ then $v_p[f]=b^3$ and $v_p[g]=-3ac^2$ where $V[p]=v_p$. In texts more abstract than Oneil's it is usually the convention to say $V[p]$ is the derivation $y^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p-x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}|_p$. Oneil, in contrast, makes an effort to keep it as concrete and calculus IIIish as possible.